# IntelliJ IDEA code inspection profile to show dependency and resolving errors

Tags: java, compiler-errors, intellij-idea, inspection

I have a multi-module project which is amidst migration process. I cannot compile some dependent module and thus it's hard to track dependency/resolving errors without explicitly opening each and every file to be checked by the editor.

I created code inspection profile which can show me syntactic errors and but I'm not able to configure it to show everything that should be red-underlined (like e.g. Eclipse problems window).

Comment: I don't get what exactly do you want to see? List of all errors?

Comment: When you try to compile the program you get a list of errors across the module/project you selected. Code inspection only applied to programs which compile, and I suggest you ensure it compiles before worrying about static analysis.

Comment: Thing is when I compile with maven compiler it reports errors in files which depend on files which depend on other files that cannot be compiled. It's pretty hard to navigate such graph. Instead, I would like to see a window, pretty much like the "Make Messages" that would list all uncompilable places and I could fix them. Aforementioned window sadly shows only 200 errors and from module that other people work on.